# Next.js Script with strategy="worker" does not work for GA

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-analytics, service-worker

I'm using next.js version 13.5.5.
I tried to load Google Analytics script with next/script worker strategy.
However, it seems to be failed.

I followed the instruction in official document https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts as the following.

My next.config.js

```
const nextConfit = {
    experimental: {
        nextScriptWorkers: true,
    },
};
...
```

My _app.tsx

```
import Script from "next/script";

...

            <Script
                id="gtag"
                strategy="worker"
                src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=*****`}
            />
            <Script
                id="gtag-init"
                strategy="worker"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
                        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];   
                        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                        gtag('js', new Date());
                        gtag('config', '*****');
                    `,
                }}
            />
...
```

This program works correctly when I set afterInteractive to strategy field.

Are there anyone who has the same problem or some ideas to resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pages router?

> Warning: The worker strategy is not yet stable and does not yet work
> with the app directory. Use with caution. [nextjs.org](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts#offloading-scripts-to-a-web-worker-experimental:%7E:text=Warning%3A%20The,Use%20with%20caution.)

If you are using the pages router, did you install partytown? `nextScriptWorkers` uses partytown under the hood and it must be installed separately. You just have to npm install it, no import is required. NextJS will automatically add the scripts to your pages.

```
npm i -D @builder.io/partytown
```

Once you have it installed, you will need to configure partytown to forward your gtag function from the main thread to the service worker. You do this by adding a configuration script in the head:

```
      <Head>
        <script
          data-partytown-config
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
          partytown = {
            lib: "/_next/static/~partytown/",
            forward: ["gtag"]
          };
        `,
          }}
        />
      </Head>
```

You also will have to make a small change to the google tag script. Notice `window.gtag` below:

```
      <Script
        strategy="worker"
        async
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=*****`}
      />
      <Script
        strategy="worker"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            window.gtag = function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', '*****', {
                page_path: window.location.pathname,
            });
        `,
        }}
      />
```

This code works for me. From the main thread, I just call window.gtag and give it the parameters as normal, it will be forwarder to the one in the service worker which will do the reporting on its behalf.

Just need to tell you that when I use the Google Tag Assistant, the response for that is blocked due to CORS policy, but the reporting works in development and in production. So, I still couldn't figure out how to get Tag Assistant to work with partytown yet.

For your reference:
[Partytown with next.js](https://partytown.builder.io/nextjs)
[next/script with worker documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts#offloading-scripts-to-a-web-worker-experimental:%7E:text=their%20use%20cases.-,Offloading%20Scripts%20To%20A%20Web%20Worker%20(Experimental),-Warning%3A%20The)